# Why does SQL Developer update Oracle Data Dictionaries while SQL*Plus does not?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer

I have the following code stored in a script file

```
create or replace package test_record
is

    type t_test_rec is record(
        name                  varchar2(64)
       ,value                 pls_integer
    );

end test_record;
/
```

When I execute it from SQL*Plus, the *_IDENTIFIERS data dictionaries are not updated to include the declaration of the type. However, if I copy/paste the same code in SQL Developer and run it as a script (F5), the mentioned data dictionaries are updated.

Even if I force a recompile of the package from SQL*Plus, the *_IDENTIFIERS tables are not updated, no matter what method I use (alter package ..., dbms_utility.compile_schema, dbms_ddl.alter, ...).

How can I force SQL*Plus to behave like SQL Developer in this respect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Developer automatically sets the below:

```
alter session set plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
```

You can use the same in SQL*Plus.

(The default is `IDENTIFIERS:NONE`.)

Comment: once you have PL/Scope going, you can take advantage of it in SQL Developer like so http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/06/plscope-support/ - much more powerful than text searches on ALL_SOURCE view to find things in your source code